# why i failed to build daemon.c which is part of git package?

Tags: git, gcc, build

there is one main() function in git/daemon.c, so i try to build it
but failed, what is the rea

```
gcc daemon.c
In file included from daemon.c:1:
cache.h:11:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
```

Comment: Does `make daemon` work better?

Comment: The concrete error seems to be that `SHA1_HEADER` needs to be defined.  Presumably the Makefile does this for you.  Ref: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/cache.h#L11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a whole bunch of compiler flags that would normally be generated by `autoconf` and used by `Makefile` and the whole rest of the build infrastructure.

Without seeing the contents of `cache.h`, we can only guess at what's actually going on, but, rather than trying to manually compile individual files, you should compile it within the framework included - the instructions are in the file named `INSTALL`.

Comment: so if i only want to build daemon.c, what is should do in order to build it?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to build just the one program, and haven't tried it myself, but `make git-daemon` might be what you're after.

Comment: how did you find this target, did you search over Makefile?

Comment: Just a hunch, really, but I did try `make -n git-daemon` to make sure it wouldn't complain first (`-n` means just print what commands would be run to build a target, rather than actually running them).